# What does Mikasa mean by "It's happening again" in the 2nd episode?

Tags: attack-on-titan

At the beginning of the 2nd episode after Eren and Mikasa are saved, the blond army guy pulls them forward, and Mikasa holds her head, has a flashback, and says "It's happening again".

What does she mean by this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After I rewatched the episode, I can firmly answer your question but be advised for there are spoilers in my answer.

When she has that flashback,

> she remembers how her family was murdered and she was thinking that she remained alone, until Eren saved her and she became part of his family. When Eren's mother dies, Mikasa experiences the same feeling of losing someone dear as she felt when her family was murdered. This is why she says "It's happening again..", because she lost a part of her family again.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I had previously watched the anime and totally forgot about that - the question came up now that I am watching it the second time. My main concern about the spoiler is whether the answer is hiding in the anime or the manga.

Comment: It was my pleasure to help you

Answer (score 0):

it's because Mikasa has

> titan blood in her, as the Ackermans are seen as titan experiments.